# genisoimage in cywin error: genisoimage: -i option no longer supported

Tags: bash, debian, cygwin

trying to build a net install iso with preseed for debian 11 in cygwin but keep gettign the error.
genisoimage: -i option no longer supported.

can't see where -i was used so unsure how to proceed.....

genisonimage 1.11.1
cygwin latest
windows 11

```
function generate_new_iso_and_cleanup() {
  local orig_iso="$1"
  local new_iso="$2"

  echo "Generating new iso: $new_iso..."
  dd if="$orig_iso" bs=1 count=432 of=mbr_template.bin

  genisoimage -r \
    -V 'Debian AUTO amd64' \
    -o "$new_iso" \
    -J -joliet-long \
    -cache-inodes \
    -isohybrid-mbr mbr_template.bin \
    -b isolinux/isolinux.bin \
    -c isolinux/boot.cat \
    -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table \
    -no-emul-boot -eltorito-alt-boot \
    -e boot/grub/efi.img -no-emul-boot \
    -isohybrid-gpt-basdat \
    -isohybrid-apm-hfsplus \
    isofiles

  rm -f mbr_template.bin
  rm -rf isofiles
}
```

tried:

xorrio, mkisofs.

expecting the iso to build, instead error code for a deprecated option that was never used.

would consider any alternative solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `genisoimage` has no obvious way how to fix that.
So I followed the changes that [grml made](https://github.com/grml/grml-live/pull/66) and it worked for me.
I replaced `genisoimage` with `xorriso -as mkisofs` as [seen here](https://github.com/grml/grml-live/blob/3152440a0deded0b946f59a18930052c70146d20/grml-live#L1577).

Comment: worth menitioning I did try with xorriso first but had a hell of a time getting the library linked right in windows, so the other part of the solution was to do this in a debian via docker then install xorriso there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are NOT reading your script

```
-e boot/grub/efi.img -no-emul-boot \
-isohybrid-gpt-basdat \
-isohybrid-apm-hfsplus \
isofiles
```

but the `-iso..` options do not exist for this version

```
$ genisoimage --help |& grep "^  -i"
  -i ADD_FILES                No longer supported
  -input-charset CHARSET      Local input charset for file name conversion
  -iso-level LEVEL            Set ISO9660 conformance level (1..3) or 4 for ISO9660 version 2
  -icon-position              Keep HFS icon position
  -input-hfs-charset CHARSET  Local input charset for HFS file name conversion
```

so `genisoimage` is complaining for

```
-i ADD_FILES                No longer supported
```

Comment: So what is the solution? And I think nobody can expect that "-i" is implied by the other arguments, since it's not explicitly called.

Comment: this is a very unhelpful answer, thanks. Prehaps if you don't have any solution to offer or nothing constructive to add, don't waste everyones time commenting?

Comment: The solution was to remove the options not valid, and eventually to replace them . I agree that the message is partially misleading but it seems you did little effort to compare the options you used with the available options. Aa additional info the program is very old not maintained and superseded by other programs https://github.com/Distrotech/cdrkit